# Generic throw function for non-nullable types

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I am trying to convert an existing project to using **nullable reference types** properties using [non-nullable properties during initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#non-nullable-properties-and-initialization).

I am using this approach for getting properties which should exist:

```cs
public class Dog
{
    private Person? _person;
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person Person
    {
        get => _person ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"Unset property {nameof(_person)}. You probably forgot to Include it");
        set => _person = value;
    }
}
```

But it's tedious to write this for almost every property, so I've tried to make a generic `ThrowOrGet()` function:

```cs
public static class Util
{
    public static T ThrowOrGet<T>([AllowNull] T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Unset property {nameof(obj)}. You probably forgot to Include it");
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```cs
public class Dog
{
    private Person? _person;
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person Person
    {
        get =>  Util.ThrowOrGet(_person); ---> "Possible null reference return"
        set => _person = value;
    }
}
```

But the the function `Util.ThrowOrGet(_person);` now says that it's a possible `null` reference return. If I inline the function, it works as intended.
Is there a way to make a generic function that does this?

Comment: This is probably not answering your question, but [the way you test for null is wrong.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/the-perfect-non-null-test/) the entire thing can be written like this: `return person ?? throw new ....` just like you did in your property. Also, [getters should probably not throw exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property) - but if you do decide to di this - I would call it `TryGet`, not `ThrowOrGet`. The throw here is not the primary thing you want your method to do - it's the last resort .

Comment: Also, your `nameof(obj)`, would simply yield "obj", which is not what you get when you inline it with `nameof(_person)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only going to use `ThrowOrGet` on reference types (which you should, as it doesn't make sense for value types), then you should declare it like this:

```cs
public static T ThrowOrGet<T>(T? obj) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"Unset property {nameof(obj)}. You probably forgot to Include it");
    }
    return obj;
}
```

This says that the function accepts a nullable argument, and always returns a non-nullable  reference. It's better to follow this pattern than rely on the attributes, as they're really just there for complex cases, which this is not.

Comment: This is correct, but as @haim770 points out as a comment on the my question; *nameof(obj), would simply yield "obj",* So you will not know which type is missing

Comment: That is also a good point, you would need to pass it as an argument for now.